# Using a background image CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to put an image into the background of my app. I seem to be running into some issues with the CSS. I have the following class:

```
.fixedBar {
    position: fixed;
    left:0%;
    top: 0%;
    width:100%;
    padding:15px 15px;
    background-color:#003c0c;
    background-image: url(NavAppPics/city-clipart-black-and-white.gif);
    background-blend-mode: multiply;
    background-size:cover;
    z-index: 6;
}
```

I am trying to use an image from a folder,  but I cannot figure out how to load the image from the folder.  I've looked at other similar questions os Stack Overflow,  but i cannot tell what I am doing differently.

As well,  I am trying to make the bottom of the image line up with the bottom of the fixed bar (the class i am using) however it seems to be lining up the image incorrectly (i switched to an online URL to test this).   any ideas or help would be greatly appreciated!

edit:

My folder structure for this section is:

- Public

  - bower_components
  - directives
  - NavAppPics

    - city-clipart-black-and-white.gif
  - styles

    - styles.css (where the class is)
  - tpl

Comment: What is your folder structure like?

Comment: Have you used dev tools before?  Check to make sure that the image path is valid, if it's not, the image will show up as a 404 in your Network tab.  URL's in your CSS are relative to the location of your css file.

Comment: You can [edit] your question to add your folder structure there instead of in the comments.

Comment: I just edited the post,  and it now contains my folder structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: The filepath must be wrong for your image. Where is the NavAppPics folder located? If it's in the root directory, add a `/` to front of the URL to tell it start from the root directory rather than the current folder:

```
background-image: url(/NavAppPics/city-clipart-black-and-white.gif);
```

As far as aligning the image to the bottom of the div:

```
background-position: center bottom;
```

More info about the `background-position` property:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp

Comment: You do **not** need quotes, it will work just fine without.

Comment: Really? Wow, I just tried it and you're right. Never knew that! Editing my answer.

Comment: You're on the right track: relative url()s in CSS files are relative to the location of the CSS file itself. So for example is the css file is in /myapp/styles/style.css and the image is in /myapp/NavAppPics/image.gif, it can be referenced by url(../NavAppPics/image.gif)

Comment: Thanks for the advice.   Like you said,  I just forgot the / infront of NavAppPics.   also,  the alignment you suggested worked perfectly.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

The address of the image is relative to the CSS style file.

Since your CSS is at `styles/styles.css`, the background image is being looked for at `styles/NavAppPics/city-clipart-black-and-white.gif`.

Specify a relative or absolute path to fix the problem:

```
background-image: url(/NavAppPics/city-clipart-black-and-white.gif);
```

Or:

```
background-image: url(../NavAppPics/city-clipart-black-and-white.gif);
```